# Publish is missing in the ribbon section after master page applied in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a publishing site in SharePoint 2013. And I have created layout and based on that layout I have created pages and I published then I have created copy of default 'olo.master' page in SP Designer and changed the name and did changes according to my application and applied it for my layout after that the publish in the ribbon is not available I don't know why.kindly help me to resolve this.Below the screenshot about my issue.

[image: The below image before master page applied it has published in the ribbon]

[image: The below image after master page applied it's missing the publish]

Comment: Is the Publish-button's element attached to the DOM, but just hidden? Is the page's current version a minor version (i.e. not published)?

Comment: No, i have inspected the source its not available in DOM itself and it is published one

Comment: Why I asked about the page's current version is, because if the current version is a major version (ends with `.0`), it is already published, and the Publish-button isn't even supposed to be available.

Comment: Ya its in major version only but while edit the page i need to publish it but here its missing so that  i went page libray and made publish and approved it